# What is MySQL "index_block_length"?

Tags: mysql, seek

MySQL official documentation [8.8.5 Estimating Query Performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/estimating-performance.html) offers the way to count disk seeks:

> log(row_count) / log(index_block_length / 3 * 2 / (index_length + data_pointer_length)) + 1

> In MySQL, an index block is usually 1,024 bytes and the data pointer is usually four bytes. For a 500,000-row table with a key value length of three bytes (the size of MEDIUMINT), the formula indicates log(500,000)/log(1024/3*2/(3+4)) + 1 = 4 seeks.

Innodb index is implemented by B-Tree, and I understand the formula. But there are two key points I cannot catch on in the sentence **In MySQL, an index block is usually 1,024 bytes and the data pointer is usually four bytes**.

My questions are:

1. Innodb is index-organized table, so index block should equal to page
   block size which is default to 16k [innodb_page_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size). I googled
   **index_block_length**, but nothing found, so why it says **usually 1,024 bytes** here? Could someone list the documentation or source
   code which explains index_block_length?
2. On 64bit version MySQL, is data pointer 8 bytes? Could someone list
   the documentation or source code which explains the length of data
   pointer ?

Comment: I wouldn't be quick to confuse data pointers with memory pointers.

Comment: That documentation page looks severely outdated. If you're using modern solid-state storage, then disk seeks is much less important. If the InnoDB pages are in RAM in the buffer pool, then disk seeks are truly irrelevant.

Comment: That's for MyISAM.  Don't use MyISAM.  How old is the book you are reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that the calculation you are looking at is for MyISAM, not for InnoDB.

The documentation has a description of the [MyISAM index file format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/the-myi-file.html), including references to the source code.

"index_block_length" refers to the block size:

```
keydef->block_length         2    04 00                   that is, 1024
```

It is specified by the system configuration variable [`myisam-block-size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-block-size), defaulting to the mentioned 1024 bytes:

> The block size to be used for MyISAM index pages.

The index entries look like this:

```
(first key value)            2    01 31                   Value is "1" (0x31).
(first key pointer)          4    00 00 00 00             Pointer is to Record
                                                          #0000.
(second key value)           2    01 33                   Value is "3" (0x33).
(second key pointer)         4    00 00 00 02             Pointer is to Record
                                                          #0002.
```

where "data_pointer_length" is the length of a "key pointer". On disk, so it has has nothing to do with using 32- or 64-bit memory pointers.

The size is set by the [`myisam_data_pointer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_data_pointer_size) configuration variable. You may notice that the default size is 6 nowaways, not 4. And with "nowaydays" I mean since MySQL 5.0.6, released in 2005. Which might give you an idea why the documentation you looked at didn't mention they are not actually talking about InnoDB.

Comment: The last paragraph in the official documentation mentions **For MyISAM tables, the key cache size is controlled by the......**, which convinced me that this post most be for InnoDB. I actually don't care about MyISAM, so it really surprised me that this is for MyISAM only. Thanks for pointing it out. Could you kindly provide some clue on estimating InnoDB index disk seeks?

Comment: The logic for InnoDB is the same, with slightly differences in pagesize and headeroverhead, and that the "key pointers" now consist of the whole primary key (which can be different for each table). But note that you actually have no practical use for that value, as there is absolutely nothing (!) you should adjust based on that information. And for theory, only the log-complexity on row number is of importance (which is a propery of the index, not the storage format or page size).

Comment: I filed a documentation request to update this in the manual: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108707

Answer (score 0):

I use the following guidelines (for InnoDB):

- A *production* system with less data than `innodb_buffer_pool_size` will (after sufficient "warm up") have everything cached in RAM.  Hence there will be no disk reads for `SELECTs` or the "read" part of write operations.
- The "fanout" of indexes (`PRIMARY KEY, or secondary indexes) can be [crudely] estimated at 100.  That is, for each node in the` B+Tree, there will be *about* 100 child nodes (or, in case of the bottom level, rows).
- Even for very large datasets, I assume that the necessary index node, plus the non-leaf nodes of the data, will be cached.  (This is actually a corollary of the "100" mentioned above -- 99% for data; 1% for non-leaf nodes.)
- When "counting the disk hits" for UUID-indexed rows or for otherwise "random" rows, 1 disk hit per row.
- For "counting the disk hits" for consecutive rows, 1 disk hit per 100 rows.
- For writes that need to change indexes, the Primary and Unique index blocks need to be fetched to check uniqueness.  Non-unique updates are handled later (cf "change buffering"), so count as zero disk hits.